# libcloud FileDeployment SSHClient._transport is NoneType

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-ec2, paramiko

```
>>>dns_node = [i for i in conn.list_nodes() if i.uuid == 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx07xxxxxxxxxx']
>>>try_script = 'path/to/somefile.py'
>>>dns_file = FileDeployment(try_script, target='/home/ec2-user')
>>>ssh_client = SSHClient(dns_node[0].public_ip[0], username='ec2-user',  key=os.path.expanduser("~/.ssh/id_rsa"))
>>>dns_file.run(dns_node, ssh_client)
```

I've verified that each of these variables assigned show me what I understand to be of the appropriate type. When I try this, I get the following:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Users/ec2-user/Envs/libcloud/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libcloud/compute/deployment.py", line 111, in run
        contents=content)
      File "/Users/ec2-user/Envs/libcloud/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libcloud/compute/ssh.py", line 174, in put
        sftp = self.client.open_sftp()
      File "/Users/ec2-user/Envs/libcloud/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 414, in open_sftp
        return self._transport.open_sftp_client()
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'open_sftp_client'`

This is what I have for the above objects:

dns_node:

```
`[<Node: uuid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, name=ec2_node1, state=0, public_ips=['xx.xxx.xxx.xx'], provider=Amazon EC2 ...>]`
```

dns_file:

`<libcloud.compute.deployment.FileDeployment object at 0x10d58de50>`

ssh_client:

```
`<libcloud.compute.ssh.ParamikoSSHClient object at 0x10d55e950>`
```

ssh_client.connect:

`<bound method ParamikoSSHClient.connect of <libcloud.compute.ssh.ParamikoSSHClient object at 0x10d55e950>>`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went to the paramiko level and discovered the private key file I referenced is encrypted, which was not being handled in the ssh connection being made. So even though there was an SSHCLient object, it was not able to connect.

pkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/id_rsa'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/Users/ec2-user/Envs/libcloud/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 198, in from_private_key_file
    key = cls(filename=filename, password=password)
  File "/Users/ec2-user/Envs/libcloud/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 51, in **init**
    self._from_private_key_file(filename, password)
  File "/Users/ec2-user/Envs/libcloud/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 163, in _from_private_key_file
    data = self._read_private_key_file('RSA', filename, password)
  File "/Users/ec2-user/Envs/libcloud/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 280, in _read_private_key_file
    data = self._read_private_key(tag, f, password)
  File "/Users/ec2-user/Envs/libcloud/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 323, in _read_private_key
    raise PasswordRequiredException('Private key file is encrypted')
paramiko.PasswordRequiredException: Private key file is encrypted

I specified a password-less key and the connection went through.

Comment: When paramiko fails to read a private key, it spits out `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'open_sftp_client'`?  That is a terrible error text.

Comment: I got this error because I had accidentally moved my call to `ssh.open_sftp()` outside of the context of the `with paramiko.SSHClient() as ssh` block.  The `ssh` object was closed and thus unusable.